# Image not uploading to folder by php using Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My HTML is as follows

```
<form id="df" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My Script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#df").submit(function(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax
      ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'review.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#preview').html(data);
        }
     });
    return false;
   });
});
```

My PHP script

```
<?php
$file = $_POST["email"];
$path = "uploads/$file";
mkdir($path);

 $t = $path.'/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
 $s = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 echo "File name : " .$_FILES['image']['name']. "</br>";
 echo "File type : " .$_FILES['image']['type']. "</br>";
 echo "File size : " .$_FILES['image']['size']. "</br>";

 move_uploaded_file($s,$t);

 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
     echo "File ". $_FILES['image']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
 }
 else {
 echo "File Not uploaded";
 }

echo '<img src="'.$t.'" alt="No image selected" class="img-responsive">';
?>
```

I get the following output.

```
File name : IMG_20150526_194112.jpg
File type : 
File size : 0
File Not uploaded
```

Subfolder with name email-id is being created in uploads folder, but image in not uploading to that folder. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: maybe the file is not an image

Comment: Maybe it has to do with permissions. Try chmod  ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data">` in your form tag.
It would be

```
<form id="df" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: My mistake, I haven't put that before. Yes I have enctype.